# Can someone explain to me what 'media' does in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Ok, I am trying to learn HTML/CSS a little more in depth and I came across something new to me in CSS. It displays like this:

```
@media(min-width: 850px) {
    .header h1 {
        font-size: 120px;
    }
}
```

I have looked for an answer everywhere but everyone tries to make the explanation way too complex. Can someone please explain to me in simple terms what *@media* does? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Media queries allow you to define rules specific to certain environments.
for example "@media(min-width: 850px)" means that this rule will only
apply for a window with width of at least 850 pixels.

this is frequently used, for example, when trying to design for mobile, since you can use rules like `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`
which means that this will only apply to screens with maximum width of 600 pixels, like smartphone.

you can easily find many tutorials about the correct way to use media queries

easy example: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: That was so easy to understand with your perfect explanation! Thank you very much! I can actually say I love the media queries now!

Comment: I am very pleased to hear that, I myself started to use them just recently while building my own site and adjusting it to both PC and mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

In just very very simple words:

Imagine the content of your 'h1' tag in your web site is set to a default of:

`font-size: 220px`;

This will be shown when the screen width is bigger than 850px.

In devices which are a width less of 850 px, the broeser will ue this directive

```
@media(min-width: 850px) {
    .header h1 {
        font-size: 120px;
    }
}
```

To re-cap:

The @media rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices.

Answer (score 0):

'@media' is nothing but css selector like 'id' and 'class'.
But '@media' is for the device screen width.
Consider you want to change the style for your data depending on the devices like PC, tablet, mobile, you have to use @media selector.
For eg : you have h1: 40px , now if you view the style in mobile it will look odd, so to change the style of the 'h1' tag we can use @media like below.

@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:767px) { h1: 14px; }

'min-width' is the min-device width and 'max-width' is the max-device width, if your screen is in between that width then the style will apply .

you can also check this by changing your desktop screen size.

Comment: `@media` is not a selector; it's a rule that contains selectors.

Comment: ya my bad that's what I meant